# Constraint on a column based on values at another column in another table

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints

I have table A which has two columns policy and rule. Table values are as below:

```
policy | rule
-------------
1  | A
-------------
1  | B
-------------
2  | C
-------------
3  | D 
-------------
```

I have another table B with a column (id).

I want to write a constraint on this table B at column (id) such that if a number of distinct policies in table A are equal to 1, then the value of (id) should always be NULL.

I am using SQL Server and I am looking at a query-based solution (not via GUI steps).

Comment: I think you've stripped away too much of your actual problem in writing this question. I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Are you saying if there is only 1 row for a policy in table A then the ID in table B should be null? How are these tables related? There needs to be a ForeignKey somewhere... but this logic, if i'm correct, should be handled in a query not in a constraint.

Answer (score 5):

Add CHECK Constraints into the table

```
create table tableA (policy int , [rule] char(1)) 
create table tableB (Id int , policy int ) 
GO
```

Function to check the constraint

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckFnctn(@policy int) -- Adapt if necessary
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @retval bit = 1
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tableA WHERE policy = @policy and policy = 1)
BEGIN
    RETURN 0
END
RETURN @retval

END;
GO
```

Add the constraint into the table

```
ALTER TABLE tableB ADD CONSTRAINT ck_id_policy_1 CHECK (dbo.CheckFnctn(policy) = 1)
```

Test

```
    INSERT tableA Values
     (1,'A')
    ,(1,'B')
    ,(2,'B')
    ,(2,'D')
GO
    (4 row(s) affected)


INSERT tableB (Id, policy) values (1,2)
GO
(1 row(s) affected)


INSERT tableB (Id, policy) values (1,1)
GO
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_id_policy_1". The conflict occurred in database "XXXX", table "dbo.tableB", column 'policy'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

If you need to check if policy 1 exists you can never insert an Id different from null. Use this function and constraint

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckFnctn(@Id int)
RETURNS bit
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @retval bit = 1
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM tableA WHERE  policy = 1 AND @Id IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    RETURN 0
END
RETURN @retval

END;
GO



ALTER TABLE tableB ADD CONSTRAINT ck_id_policy_1 CHECK (dbo.CheckFnctn(Id) = 1) 

INSERT tableB (Id, policy) values (1,2)
GO
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_id_policy_1". The conflict occurred in database "XXXXX", table "dbo.tableB", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.

INSERT tableB (Id, policy) values (NULL,1)
GO
(1 row(s) affected)
```